# Is the $x$-axis a differentiable function?

Tags: derivatives

Is the $x$-axis a differentiable function?

Comment: What is your question? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: "The x-axis" is the function $f(x) = 0$, which infinetly differentiable, every derivative is identical $0$.

Comment: I've edited your post to make it more understandable - please verify that I didn't change the intended meaning of your question.

Comment: The x-axis is not a function. It is a set of points. You can associate it to the zero function as per @MaximilianGerhardt's comment, but that is a bit of an artificial association.

Comment: @downvoters I don't think that English is OP's first language, so perhaps instead of just downvoting the question and driving a new user away from the site, it would be more productive to leave a comment as qbert has. Looking at OP's past questions no one has bothered to tell this newbie how to post. I realise that OP should have read the tour, but it's possible that since English is not native to them that they didn't understand some parts of it.

Comment: Actually my question is Is y=0 is a differentiable function?

Comment: @taniyakapoor yes,  it is.  The derivative is again,  $y=0$ and so forth. It's infinitely differentiable,  and is also infinitely integrateable,  as are all polynomials (it is effectively one,  as it can be written as $0x^0$)